# Any Cloudflare's DNS over TLS (DoT) check + DNSSEC test?

Tags: dns, router, dnssec, cloudflare, dot

In my original question from 2020, I was unsuccessful in my effort to setup [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/dns/)'s (link to docs) **[DNS over TLS (DoT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_over_TLS)** (link to wiki) in my old, and now decomissioned, router:
[Does Cloudflare's DNS over TLS (DoT) implement DNSSEC too?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/239698/82570)

---

Now, having more spare money, I have bought [Turris Omnia 2020 router](https://www.turris.com/en/omnia/specifications/) (link to specs).

There it is very simple to enable DNS over TLS (DoT) and even [**DNSSEC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System_Security_Extensions) (link to wiki) like this:

[image: Turris Omnia 2020 - DNS settings]

---

My question is how do I verify both of:

1. Cloudflare's DNS over TLS (DoT)
2. DNSSEC

be in use from/on my end station running Linux Mint 20.x + Windows 10 Pro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for the Cloudflare's DNS over TLS (DoT), one can visit:
https://1.1.1.1/help

where I finally get the confirmation like this:
[image: Cloudflare's DNS over TLS (DoT)]

---

And as for the DNSSEC, I found this online test:
https://dnssec.vs.uni-due.de

where I finally get the confirmation like this:

[image: DNSSEC test]

Hope it helps!